# How make VueJS understand localized numbers?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, localization

Let's figure a simple sum app. two inputs, `a` and `b` and a `c` result.

we have this markup

```
<div id="app">
<input v-model.number="v1">
<input v-model.number="v2">
{{v3}}
</div>
```

and this Vue script

```
var vm = new Vue ({
    el: "#app",
       data: {
        a:0,
        b:0,
    },        
    computed: {
     c:function(){
            return this.a + this.b; 
        }
    }
})
```

this works great except that I'm working with localized numbers. that means. using comma "," instead of dot "." and dot instead of comma .

entering number with decimal places confuses vue, and it are not able to make a correct sum.

What can I do in order to make VueJS understand localized number input and them make the correct sum?

for instance in pt-BR locale: `1.000,30` + `100,30` = `1.100,60`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, first of all, a number is just a number. Internally, the `.` will always be the decimal separator.

So a number like `1.100,60` is the number `1100.60` just *printed* in a different locale.

To print it, just use **[JavaScript's `Number#toStringLocale()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toLocaleString)**:

```js
var vm = new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    a: 1110.12,
    b: 10000.11,
  },
  computed: {
    c: function() {
      return this.a + this.b;
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2"></script>

<div id="app">
  <input v-model.number="a">
  <input v-model.number="b">
  <hr>
  Browser's locale: {{c.toLocaleString()}}<br>
  en-US locale: {{c.toLocaleString('en-US')}}<br>
  pt-BR locale: {{c.toLocaleString('pt-BR')}}<br>
</div>
```

## Using a formatted `<input>`

Now, if you want the `<input>` to take localized numbers, that is not a problem specific to Vue, but to JavaScript and the browser in general. This means that you'll have to find a custom component that implements the behavior you want (formatting in the `<input>`).

Luckily, a quick search [brings one that seems to to the job](https://github.com/kevinongko/vue-numeric):

```js
Vue.use(VueNumeric.default)
var vm = new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    a: 1110.12,
    b: 10000.11,
  },
  computed: {
    c: function() {
      return this.a + this.b;
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/accounting-js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue-numeric"></script>

<div id="app">
  Formatted inputs:
  <vue-numeric currency="R$" separator="," precision="2" v-model="a"></vue-numeric>
  <vue-numeric currency="$" separator="." precision="2" v-model="b"></vue-numeric>
  <hr>
  Browser's locale: {{c.toLocaleString()}}<br>
  en-US locale: {{c.toLocaleString('en-US')}}<br>
  pt-BR locale: {{c.toLocaleString('pt-BR')}}<br>
</div>
```

Again, the component just changes the input field. The number will still be just a number and the "printing" will still have to be done using `.toLocaleString()`.

Comment: vue-numeric looks promising, but doesn't seem to support Vue 3 and TypeScript, unfortunately.

Answer (score -1):

Using vuex as store my approach on doing this was to use [two-way-computed-property](https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/forms.html#two-way-computed-property) with a getter and a setter.

The getter takes the data (in float) out of the store and shows it in the input-field formated with .toLocalString().

The setter takes the input as a local-formatted string and replaces ( .replace() ) the dots with "" and the commas with "."- after doing this string needs to be parsed as float ( parseFloat(string) ) and then the action for updating the store will be dispatched.